# Why Mysql always returns zero value withing stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, zero

I use following to reserve id if not exist in table;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_ch_id_from_ych_id`(pYch_id nvarchar(100), pIP_address nvarchar(30))
BEGIN
declare ch_id bigint;
set ch_id =(select ifnull(max(ch_id),0)ch_id from channels where ych_id=pYch_id);
if(ch_id<1) then 
    INSERT INTO channels
    (ych_id, Name, Last_IP, Active, Banned, Qualified, ReportedCount)
    VALUES
    (pYch_id,Name,pIP_address,1      ,0     ,0        ,0);
end if;
select ifnull(max(ch_id),0) ch_id from channels where ych_id=pYch_id;
END
```

However, it always return zero when called as below;

```
call get_ch_id_from_ych_id ('A',''); //not work
select ifnull(max(ch_id),0) ch_id from channels where ych_id='A'; //works
```

Data row is inserted without problem and exist in table. but in first line,
it returns zero. when I run sql in workbench it returns correct value. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give you local variable the same name as a table column. When you refer to `ch_id` in the query, it uses the variable rather than the column.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_ch_id_from_ych_id`(pYch_id nvarchar(100), pIP_address nvarchar(30))
BEGIN
declare temp_ch_id bigint;
set temp_ch_id =(select ifnull(max(ch_id),0)ch_id from channels where ych_id=pYch_id);
if(temp_ch_id<1) then 
    INSERT INTO channels
    (ych_id, Name, Last_IP, Active, Banned, Qualified, ReportedCount)
    VALUES
    (pYch_id,Name,pIP_address,1      ,0     ,0        ,0);
end if;
select ifnull(max(ch_id),0) ch_id from channels where ych_id=pYch_id;
END
```

Comment: Barmar, thanks that was the problem, now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can so this in MySQL.
You need to convert the stored procedure to a function or use an OUT parameter to return values.

Source: [MySQL - Returning Single Value from Stored Procedure](https://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/techniques/return-value-from-procedure)

Comment: What can't you do? If the procedure contains a `SELECT` statement, its result set becomes the result set of the `CALL` statement.

Comment: It even says that on the page you linked to. The third option is "Use result set to return a value"